# HSSFCellStyle count : is there any limitation?

Tags: apache-poi

I'm creating a HSSFWorkbook and I'm wondering if there is any limitation about the number of HSSFCellStyle that a HSSFWorkbook can contain ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a HSSF requirement per-se, it's a requirement imposed by the Excel `.xls` file format.

Apache POI provides an easy way to get the limits of a given Excel file format, through the class [SpreadsheetVersion](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/SpreadsheetVersion.html). The method you'll want is [getMaxCellStyles()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/SpreadsheetVersion.html#getMaxCellStyles())

From that, you can discover that the maximum number of Cell Styles in a given `.xls` (HSSF) Excel workbook is 4000.

You can also get the same information from the Microsoft documentation, the pages are [this for Excel 2003 / .xls](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP005199291.aspx) and [this for Excel 2007 / .xlsx](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010073849.aspx)